# IEEE754 32-bit single precision format

Tags: computer-arithmetic

I have a question like this:

Show how the number $-12.75$D is stored in the computer's storage using IEEE754 32-bit single precision format. You are required to show your conversion steps clearly.

My answer is:

$-12.75\mathrm{D}=-1100.11\mathrm{B}$
normalization: $-1.10011\times 2^3$
$E(D)=127+3=130\mathrm{D}$
$E(B)=130\mathrm{D}=1000\ 0010\mathrm{B}$
sign: negative: $1$
$IEEE 754(SP)=1\ 10000010\ 10011....\mathrm{B}$

Is it correct?

Comment: $-12.75{\tt D} = -1100.1\color{red}{1}{\tt B}$. Try [this](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) yourself to see the pattern.

Comment: @achillehui oops thank you but how to count that?

Comment: $0.75{\tt D} = 0.5{\tt D} + 0.25{\tt D} = 1/2 + 1/2^2 = 0.10{\tt B} + 0.01{\tt B}$

Comment: i have ady edit the answer is it correct?? thank you very much @achillehui

Comment: The result now matches what returned from the link I posted above.

Comment: i knew the answer thanks ya @achillehui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your final version is correct.
$\require{enclose}
\def\xD{{}_{10}}
\def\xB{{}_{2}}
$

Given any real number, if its representation in basis $b$ ($2 \le b \le 10$) is given by
a string $???$ consists solely of digits and at most one decimal point, we will use
the notation $???_{b}$ to label it.

Since $$
-12.75\xD = -(2^3 + 2^2 + 0 + 0 + 2^{-1} + 2^{-2}) = -1100.11\xB = -1.10011\xB \times 2^3$$
the sign bit $S$ is $1$, exponent $E$ is $3\xD$ and the mantissa $M$ is 
$1.10011\xB$.

For [IEEE754 single precision numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32), we use

- $1$ bit for sign, $S = 1 \mapsto \color{red}{\enclose{box}{1}}$
- $8$ bit for exponent but encoded with an offset of $127$. So 
  $$E = 3\xD \mapsto 3\xD + 127\xD = 130\xD = (2^7 + 2^1) = 1000 0010\xB
  \mapsto \color{green}{\enclose{box}{1000\;0010}}
  $$
- $24$ bit for mantissa but the leading bit is implicit and only $23$ bits are stored.
  $$M = 1.10011\xB
  \mapsto 1\color{blue}{\enclose{box}{100\;1100\;0000\;0000\;0000\;0000}}$$

Under IEEE754, $-12.75\xD$ will be encoded as

$$\color{red}{\enclose{box}{1}}\!-\!\color{green}{\enclose{box}{1000\;0010}}\!-\!\color{blue}{\enclose{box}{100\;1100\;0000\;0000\;0000\;0000}}$$

There are several single precision converter on the web.
The one I used for reference is [this](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html). Play with it and it will help you understand how floating points numbers
are encoded in this format.

Comment: Weird... why  do I read $3{\tt D}$  as a single hexadecimal number instead of ${\tt D}$ meaning "decimal"?

Comment: @JanDvorak I change the notation and no more confusion between $3_{10}$ and the hexadecimal $3D$.

Comment: Much better, thanks!